# Files locked when reinstalling under OS 7 Horus

Tags: files

When reinstalling Elementary os 7 Horus all files from connected drives appear locked , I can open new downloaded files but can never delete them .
Does anyone know what the cause of this is because these are not even old files on the drive but new ones , I have to delete them each time under windows . :-(

Comment: Are the connected drives all NTFS? Are these physically connected? Or over a network?